# Getting `TypeError: jest.fn is not a function`

Tags: javascript, jasmine, mocking, jestjs

I'm trying to create the following unit test using Jest.

```
jest.dontMock("pointsAwardingActions.js");
describe("points awarding actions", () => {
  describe("award points", () => {
    it("should dispatch begin ajax action", () => {
      var pointsAwardingActions = require("pointsAwardingActions.js");
      const mockedDispatch = jest.fn();
    });
  });
});
```

But I'm getting the following error after running `npm test`.

> TypeError: jest.fn is not a function

This is some section of my `package.json`:

```
{
  "scripts": {
    "test": "jest"
  },
  "author": "alayor",
  "license": "ISC",
  "jest": {
    "scriptPreprocessor": "<rootDir>/node_modules/babel-jest",
    "testFileExtensions": ["spec.js"],
    "moduleFileExtensions": ["js"],
    "collectCoverage": "true"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "babel-cli": "6.8.0",
    "babel-core": "6.8.0",
    "babel-jest": "^6.0.1",
    "babel-loader": "6.2.4",
    "babel-plugin-react-display-name": "2.0.0",
    "babel-polyfill": "6.8.0",
    "babel-preset-es2015": "6.6.0",
    "babel-preset-react": "6.5.0",
    "babel-preset-react-hmre": "1.1.1",
    "expect": "1.19.0",
    "express": "4.13.4",
    "jest": "^0.1.40",
    "jest-cli": "^0.8.1",
    ...
  }
}
```

What could be the reason I'm getting that error?

Answer (score 34, accepted):

The [`jest` object](https://facebook.github.io/jest/docs/en/jest-object.html) is automatically in scope within every test file, so there's no need to import it explicitly. If you do want to import the `jest` object directly, you want to import the jest-mock module, not the jest-cli module, via:

```
// Not necessary inside a Jest test file
import jest from 'jest-mock';

const mock = jest.fn();
```

Comment: this is what i looking for, this solve spyOn is not a function, also fn is not a function

Comment: I'm new to redux and jest and i can't describe the number of hours searching for this. You saved my life man

Answer (score 6):

It is a bit weird that documentation isn't mentioning that `jest` is not `require('jest');` but `require('jest-mock')`, the following code should work on v22:

```
const jest = require('jest-mock');
const spy = jest.fn();
```

Comment: "The jest object is automatically in scope within every test file." https://facebook.github.io/jest/docs/en/jest-object.html

Comment: @RickHanlonII Every test file... but not files in __mocks__ directories.

Comment: Another situation this is useful: playing on Node's console, you need to require it specifically

Answer (score 3):

You’re using a very old version of Jest that [don’t support `jest.fn`](https://github.com/facebook/jest/blob/master/website/blog/2016-04-12-jest-11.md). Jest has significantly improved since then and I highly recommend you to update to the latest version.

Also they don’t do auto mocking now.

Comment: @TFischer did you try the answer by Rick? https://stackoverflow.com/a/48977663/3163075

Answer (score -1):

It's already included in your Jest package, so please make sure that you type correct like this: (`"mockReturnValue"`).

It will clear your error.